# inner methods on attributes in respond_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I'm rendering a serialized JSON response with the following code:

```
respond_with(@posts, :only => [:id, :content, :created_at], 
        :include => { :user => { :only => [:id, :name] }, 
                      :comments => { :only => [:content, :created_at] }})
```

the response is parsed in JAVA code so I want to convert the created_at value to a format that I can use, how do i run a method on each created_at value (even .to_i for example) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it defining a new method inside comments model e.g.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecode::Base
  ...
  def created_at_to_i
     created_at.to_i
  end 
  ...
end
```

and while rendering

```
respond_with(@posts, :only => [:id, :content, :created_at], 
        :include => { :user => { :only => [:id, :name] }, 
                      :comments => { :only => [:content, :created_at_to_i] }})
```

Comment: it does't work. there is no created_at related field in the JSON output

Answer (score 0):

Define method in each model like :

```
def formated_created_at
  self.created_at.strftime(FORMAT_AS_YOU_LIKE)
end
```

At the time of rendering use it like :

> respond_with(@posts, :only => [:id, :content, :formated_created_at
>   , 
>           :include => { :user => { :only => [:id, :name] }, :comments => { :only => [:content, :formated_created_at
>   ] }})

**EDITED :**

Instead of using the :only in respond_with , you can create your own hash and pass it to respond_with .
Like :

```
post_hash= { :post => [{:id => 1, :content => "abc", :created_at => self.formated_created_at,:user => {:id => 1, :name => 'Vik' }, :comments => { :content => "comment text", :created_at => self.comment.formated_created_at}] }
respond_with(post_hash)
```

And I think u can format the created_at at the time of displaying , via javascript, jQuery .

Comment: it does't work. there is no created_at related field in the JSON output

Comment: can you please try : 
self.formated_created_at OR
self.comment.formated_created_at

Comment: doesn't work:

    NoMethodError:
       undefined method `formated_created_at' for :self:Symbol

Comment: that hash is for a single post, i want to output an array of posts

Comment: make it as array of hash :

post_hash= { :posts => [{:id => 1, :content => "abc"...}, {:id => 2, :content => "abc"...},{:id => 3, :content => "abc"...}] }
respond_with(post_hash)

Comment: isn't there a simpler way to do what I want without manually building an hash for each one of the array members ?

Comment: is there a way to do this on the entire array and not go one by one on it's memebers ?